# Cannot assign type to same type in dart

Tags: dart

I have this code below. I want to create BST but when I try to implement compareTO method inside get function I get the "The argument type 'Key' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'.dartargument_type_not_assignable" error which does not make sense to me because it basically says cannot assign to the same type. Can anybody explain this? I commented on the erogenous line below.

```
class Key extends Comparable<Key> {
  num key;

  Key(this.key);

  @override
  int compareTo(Key other) {
    return key.compareTo(other.key);
  }
}

class Value {
  dynamic value;
}

class Node {
  Key key;
  Value value;
  Node? left, right;

  Node(this.key, this.value);
}

class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
  Node? root;

  Value get(Key key) {
    Node? currentNode = root;
    while (currentNode != null) {
    int compare = key.compareTo(currentNode.key); // The argument type 'Key' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
    if (compare > 0) {
      currentNode = currentNode.right;
    } else if (compare < 0) {
      currentNode = currentNode.left;
    } else {}
    ...
    ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to rename `BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>` into `BST<T extends Comparable<T>, Value>` to avoid confusion between the different identifiers `Key`s.

In `BST`, `Key` (let's call it `T`) refers to a generic type (=`T`) that extends `Comparable<T>`.

So `T extends Comparable<T>`

In`BST.get(Key key)`, `Key` still refers to the generic type `T`.

So `key` has the type `T`.

Now I supposed that `currentNode.key` is of type `Key` (!= `T`).

`key.comparyTo(x)` requires `x` to be a `T` while `currentNode.key` is not (it is `Key`).

---

It is hard to be clear when you have 2 identifiers with the same name (`Key`).

As I said at the beginning of my answer, rename

```dart
class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {}
```

into

```dart
class BST<T extends Comparable<T>, Value> {}
```

to have a more understandable error message.

When you do it, the error message should become:

```
The argument type 'Key' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.
```

Comment: I've often said "when you can pick something arbitrary for an identifier, best not to shadow things already in your namespace" :)